# SQLite3 - Calculated SELECT with padding and concatenation

Tags: sqlite, concatenation, calculated-columns, zero-padding

I have the following SQLite table (a stub of the real table which has a few other columns)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fingers(id INTEGER,intLL INTEGER,fracLat INTEGER,fracLng INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

A typical entry in this table would be along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO fingers(id,intLL,fracLat,fracLng) VALUES(1,12899,42513,4025);
```

From time-to-time I need to query this table to pull out rows for matching `intLL` values in such a way that a calculated value meets a variable condition.  For example

```
SELECT * FROM fingers WHERE intLL = 12899 AND ('8508' = (CAST((ROUND(CAST(fracLat AS REAL)/500)) 
AS INTEGER) || CAST((ROUND(CAST(fraCLng AS REAL)/500)) AS INTEGER)));
```

**Explanation**

- Transform the `fractLat` and `fracLng` columns by dividing them by 10,250 or 500. The `CAST AS REAL` is required to prevent the default integer division that would be performed by SQLite
- Round the decimal result to the closest integer. After rounding you will by default get a value with a trailing `.0`. The `CAST AS INTEGER` ensures that this is removed
- Concatenate the two parts. The concatenation is going wrong.  In the present case the concatenated result would be **858** which is not what I want
- Compare against an incoming value: 8508 in this case.

My questions

1. How can I pad the two parts with 0s when required prior to concatenation so as to ensure that they have the same number of digits
2. Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pad `0`s is to concatenate `00` at the start of the number and with `SUBSTR()` return the last 2 chars.
Also, you can divide by `500.0` to avoid integer division:

```
SELECT * FROM fingers 
WHERE intLL = 12899 
AND '8508' = SUBSTR('00' || CAST(fracLat / 500.0 AS INTEGER), -2) || 
             SUBSTR('00' || CAST(fraCLng / 500.0 AS INTEGER), -2)
```

Another way to do it is with the function `printf()` which formats a number:

```
SELECT * FROM fingers 
WHERE intLL = 12899 
AND '8508' = printf('%02d', fracLat / 500.0) || 
             printf('%02d', fraCLng / 500.0)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=deae4c455092f741c8b17d2769ed8117).